# Double integral of a function one of whose parameters is drawn from a Gabor function

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-theory, definite-integrals

Suppose I have a probability density function $\phi$ with three parameters $\mu, \kappa$, and $\xi$.  The PDF is such that

\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\phi(x, \mu, \kappa, \xi)dx=1.
\end{align}

Here, $x$ is an observed value, for which $\phi$ returns the associated probability density.

Now suppose I want to set $\mu$ differently for each observation.

I define a new function (a Gabor function) as follows:

\begin{align}
b &= G(y, h, w)\\
&= h e^{-(wy)^2}\sin(wy).
\end{align}

What I want to know is, does the following double integral

\begin{align}
\int^\pi_{-\pi}\int^\pi_{-\pi}\phi\big(x, \mu + G(y, h, w), \kappa, \xi\big)dxdy
\end{align}

evaluate to 1?

My gut tells me it does, because the integral of $G$ over that range is 0.  Hence (if my intuition is right), $G$ won't push the integral in either direction away from the value for the original $\phi$ function (i.e., 1).

Note: Normally I would compute the answer myself using software, but in this case the function $\phi$ is so hairy that computing the double integral takes a very, very long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whereas the single integral fixing $y$ at 0 is 1, the double integral is $2\pi$.

This comes from the fact that the marginal density of $y$ is $1/(2\pi)$.

What we have inside the double integral is the conditional density of $x|y$.  Multiplying by the marginal density of $y$ gives the joint density, for which the double integral is 1: $2\pi \times 1/(2\pi) = 1$.

Note that these results depend on the specific specifications of neither the function $G$ nor the function $\phi$ (so long as $\phi$ is a PDF).

They depend only on the knowledge that $y$ is sampled from a uniform distribution.  If $y$ were sampled from a different distribution, the marginal density of this distribution would have to be substituted in above.